# Cannot update iPhone 4 on iTunes

Tags: itunes, iphone

My internet connection works perfectly but when trying to update my iPhone 4, it says it 'cannot connect to server'?

Comment: Is this an iPhone 4, or updating an iPhone to iOS 4.0? Additionally does the 'Cannot connect to server' error appear when you try to access the iTunes Store? Does the error appear when attempting to download the update, or when checking for an update to your phone?

Comment: Same problem when I tried. mine is iPhone 4. suppose to be a factory unlocked version from Canada.. although I reside in India now. Clicking at the "more information" button, redirects with some error code -3259. Sometimes, it starts downloading some mb and then shows that error!!

Answer (score 1):

The servers might just be bogged down. It happens occasionally.

Comment: well that's it but they should make this explicit like "back in x minutes" instead of just "cannot connect to server"

Comment: @asksuperuser So they put on a back up server, indicating how long it would take for the server to kick back in? Right...

Answer (score -1):

Try download firmware use torrent tracker and update manually (press alt or shift (i've forgotten) and press update, choose downloaded file and waiting...